# Can't FTP to /var/www/html on Ubuntu (groups set...)

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, permissions, ftp, groups

So I'm having some issues with vsftpd.

I need the webroot to be in /var/www/public because I have multiple users accessing it, so I can't put it in a users directory. Now that directory has *"chown -R www-data:www-data"* set and I've verified with ls -la, it's all owned by www-data.

Doing groups on the user that I'm FTP'ing with returns *"username sudo www-data"*.

If i try to FTP with that user with basedir as /var/www/public it shoots me "No permission" in Dreamweaver and "Failed to change directory" in Cyberduck, which I assume is a permission problem as well.

How do I fix this? Again, user directory != an option.

**Here are the permissions leading up to the folder:**

```
/var - drwxr-xr-x   13 root root 4096 May  6 19:52 var

/var/www - drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data 4096 May 19 20:01 www

/var/www/public - drwxrwxr-x 7 www-data www-data 4096 May 19 20:01 public
```

---

**EDIT:** I could fix this by using ProFTPd with root privs, that is pretty unsafe. I would reall appreciate a reply to make it work with vsftpd.

PS. Ubuntu 14.04, Apache2, VSFTPd

Comment: What are the permissions on the folder itself?

Comment: you should post the vsftpd log file by 'tail -f /var/log/xferlog' ,when you ftp to server.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the permissions on `/var` /`var/www` and /`var/www/public` are set to allow suitable access to the user you are using.